# access PHP session value in other file's javascript

Tags: javascript, php, modal-dialog

I'm trying to do a modal on a PHP file and I'm managing the form from the modal on another javascript file.

My question is: How can I access a session value in that javascript file.

Here is my HTML code on a php file:

```
<dialog class="modal" id="modal">
        <div class=modal-header>
            <h1>Insert a term</h1>
        </div>
        <form class="form" method="dialog">
            <label>Title</label>
            <input type="text" id="title">
            <label>Description</label>
            <input type="text" id="description" placeholder="(Max 140 characters)">
            <div class="btn2-group">
                <button class="button" id="submitForm" type="submit">submit form</button>
                <button class="close button"><b>Close</b></button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </dialog>
```

And here is my modal.js :

```
const modal = document.querySelector("#modal");
const openModal = document.querySelector(".open-button");
const closeModal = document.querySelector(".close");
const submitForm = document.querySelector("#submitForm")

openModal.addEventListener("click", () => {
    modal.showModal();
});

closeModal.addEventListener("click", () => {
    modal.close();
});

submitForm.addEventListener("click", () => {
    var title = document.getElementById("title").value;
    var desc = document.getElementById("description").value;
    var x = "<?=$_SESSION['user_id']?>";
    if (title && desc) {
        alert(x);
    } else {
        print("Please fill everything up!");
    }
 })
```

Comment: Could this work with an hidden input inside your HTML in PHP, where you put your `<?=$_SESSION['user_id']?>` as a value and then get the hidden input value with JS?

Comment: @KurtLagerbier It isn't ideal, but I can make that happen. You recommend me getting that hidden value by `document.getElementById` as well?

Comment: Let me try to put my idea into an answer. Give me a sec. please...

Comment: Why do you need this `var x = "<?=$_SESSION['user_id']?>";` at all in your JS? If you need to call the back end, you can get that value there instead.

Comment: @M.Eriksson I was going to process the form in JS, do you recommend I manage it in PHP? I'm still a student that's why I'm asking for opinions

Comment: Think about it. You're letting PHP output the user id from a session variable, just to be able to send it back to PHP. From PHP > JS > PHP. When you send the form to JS, you don't need to pass the id since PHP can simply get it from the session when it receives the form data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my sggestion:

Don't output the user id in the JS and remove it from the form altogether.

If you know it suppose to be the current user, then fetch the user id from the session in PHP on the page that receives the form request instead. You don't need to send it to the client just to get it back in PHP.

If you do send it from the client, you still need to validate/verify the id since you should never ever trust trust data you get from the client. Anyone can modify that ID in their client/browser and send what ever they want.

Answer (score 1):

Generate the JS file from PHP, call it `modal.js.php`.

```
<?php
session_start();
header("Content-type: text/javascript");
?>
const modal = document.querySelector("#modal");
const openModal = document.querySelector(".open-button");
const closeModal = document.querySelector(".close");
const submitForm = document.querySelector("#submitForm")

openModal.addEventListener("click", () => {
    modal.showModal();
});

closeModal.addEventListener("click", () => {
    modal.close();
});

submitForm.addEventListener("click", () => {
    var title = document.getElementById("title").value;
    var desc = document.getElementById("description").value;
    var x = <?= json_encode($_SESSION['user_id']) ?>;
    if (title && desc) {
        alert(x);
    } else {
        print("Please fill everything up!");
    }
 })
```

Comment: I tried your answer, but now my modal just doesn't open and yes I changed my file to modal.js.php

Comment: I took the liberty to fix the XSS vulnerabilty. All output must be escaped manually for the context it's used in (here JavaScript) when using plain PHP for templating.

Comment: @MiguelRodrigues Are you loading this script after logging in? It won't work if `modal.js.php` is loaded on the login page itself, since the session variable won't be set yet.

Comment: @Peter Thanks. I was fixated on the issue of getting the PHP to execute, not the design of the PHP.

Comment: Thank you, do you know how should I "call" this file in my php file? I guess `<script src="modal.js.php"></script>` won't work

Comment: Sure, that's exactly how you call it.

Comment: @Barmar yes. I'm loading the script on index.php and I cannot open that page if I'm not logged in. So yes.
I still cannot open my modal for some reason, I called the script correctly on index.php as I commented before and I'm using the exact same code from this answer. Any help?

Comment: I think I didn't express myself correctly. Every time I go to index.php I am already logged in and then I load the script, so the variable should exist already

Comment: I would question why the user id needs to be in the JS at all, tbh. If it's needed in a request to PHP, then PHP can just fetch it from the session instead. The down side with generating the JS using PHP is that it can't be cached (since the session can change from request to request). It also makes it harder to solve if you're using any type of build system for the JS.

Comment: In that case I think it should work.

Answer (score 1):

As I suggested in my comment, I would try to add a hidden input to PHP HTML code like that:

```
<dialog class="modal" id="modal">
    <div class=modal-header>
        <h1>Insert a term</h1>
    </div>
    <form class="form" method="dialog">
        <label>Title</label>
        <input type="text" id="title">
        <label>Description</label>
        <input type="text" id="description" placeholder="(Max 140 characters)">
        <input type="hidden" id="user-id" name="userId" value="<?=$_SESSION['user_id']?>">
        <div class="btn2-group">
            <button class="button" id="submitForm" type="submit">submit form</button>
            <button class="close button"><b>Close</b></button>
        </div>
    </form>
</dialog>
```

And then get this by JS like that:

```
const modal = document.querySelector("#modal");
const openModal = document.querySelector(".open-button");
const closeModal = document.querySelector(".close");
const submitForm = document.querySelector("#submitForm");
const userID = document.getElementById("user-id").value;

openModal.addEventListener("click", () => {
    modal.showModal();
});

closeModal.addEventListener("click", () => {
    modal.close();
});

submitForm.addEventListener("click", () => {
    var title = document.getElementById("title").value;
    var desc = document.getElementById("description").value;
    if (title && desc) {
        alert(userID);
    } else {
        print("Please fill everything up!");
    }
})
```

Of course you could get the hidden input value in different ways, like:

```
const userID = document.getElementsByName("userId")[0];
```

UPDATE:

Well, I agree with the arguments of M. Eriksson in the comments. Maybe the logic behind this code may should be reconsidered.